# Display a column value in label with gnuplot

Tags: animation, label, gnuplot, particles

I have a program that generates a file with the positions of particles in a box, and data contains also the pressure inside the box (every second let's say). With gnuplot I animate the particles in a loop but I want to display the pressure in a label. Is it possible ?

[image]

Here's the file. Pressure is in 4th column

[image]

My code :

```
# Titre du graphique
set title "Mouvement de particules d'Hélium (R = 3e-2 {/Helvetica=10 \305) \n sur une surface de      4 {/Helvetica=10 \305^{2}}"
set xlabel "L {/Helvetica=10 (\305)}"
set ylabel "L {/Helvetica=10 (\305)}"
set style line 2 lc rgb 'blue' pt 7 # cercle
set style fill solid 0.4
unset key
set size square
infile = 'particules.dat'
#stats infile using 1:2 name 'data' nooutput
k=21
do for [i=0:k] {
labels(x,y) = stringcolumn(3)
stats [*:*] infile using 5 name 'pression' nooutput
set label 1 sprintf("Pression : ", pression) at screen 0.2,0.9
plot infile index i using 1:2 with circles ls 2
pause 1.0
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, provide your sample data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so elegant, but you can use multiplot. Using this as the core of your loop:

```
set multiplot

set size 1,1
set origin 0,0

set border
set xtics; set ytics

set xlabel "L {/Helvetica=10 (\305)}"
set ylabel "L {/Helvetica=10 (\305)}"
set title "Mouvement de particules d'Hélium (R = 3e-2 {/Helvetica=10 \305) \n sur une surface de      4 {/Helvetica=10 \305^{2}}"

plot infile index i using 1:2 with circles ls 2

set border 0
unset xtics; unset ytics
unset xlabel; unset ylabel
unset title

set origin -0.35,0.395
plot infile index i u (0):(0):4 w labels

unset multiplot
```

[image: MWE]

You may have to play with the current `origin` values.

Comment: have you tested your code? If you try to plot `with labels` outside the plot range either gnuplot adjusts the range accordingly (then it will be not outsdide anymore) or if you fix the range,e.g. `set xrange[-1:1]; set yrange[-1:1]` then it will not be plotted because it is outside. I guess you would somehow need some additional settings.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. I have just a problem with the label "Pression". It appears twice, at the top and in the middle of the graph. How did you solved this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't reproduce the problem :( Maybe you should put the `set label 1...` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tom Solid originally suggested, you can nevertheless do it via plotting `with labels`.
The "trick" is to use `offset`. This will give a label, e.g. an offset of `1.2` character sizes upwards. With this, apparently, the label is even placed outsize the graph area. Check `help label` and there the option `offset`, which will also work in the plotting style `with labels`, although it is not explicitely mentioned in the documentation (see `help labels`).
Furthermore, you can avoid to print many labels on top of each other if you limit it to one row, i.e. `every ::0::0`, check `help every`.

If you want an animated GIF file, there is the `terminal gif` with the option `animate`, however, unfortunatly the image quality is not that great. I would recommend to create individual PNG frames, e.g. with `term pngcairo` and put them together to an animated GIF with some other software.

**Code:**

```
### animation with label from data
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
do for [p=0:10] {
    do for [i=1:50] {
        print sprintf("%.3f %.3f %.2f %.2f",rand(0)*2-1,rand(0)*2-1,0.03,p/10.)
    }
    print "\n"; print "\n"
}
set print

set size ratio -1
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
unset key
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set title "Mouvement de particules d'Hélium (R = 3e-2 Å)\nsur une surface de 4 Å^2"
myLabel(col) = sprintf("Pression: %.2f",column(col))

do for [p=0:10] {
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 index p w circles ls 1, \
         ''    u (-1):(1):(myLabel(4)) index p every ::0::0 w labels offset 0,1.2
    pause 1.0
}

# additionally create an animated GIF file
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 100 font ",10"
set output "myHeAtoms.gif"
do for [p=0:10] {
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 index p w circles ls 1, \
         ''    u (-1):(1):(myLabel(4)) index p every ::0::0 w labels offset 0,1.2
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result 1:** (single PNG output from wxt terminal)

[image]

**Result 2:** Animated GIF (well, decent image quality and I don't know why the points apparently have slightly different size):

[image]